# Delete "0" or "1" from the end of each line, except the first line

Tags: awk, sed

the input file looks like

```
Kick-off team   68  0
Ball safe       69  1
Attack          77  8
Attack          81  4
Throw-in        83  0
Ball possession 86  3
Goal kick       100 10
Ball possession 101 1
Ball safe       114 13
Throw-in        123 9
Ball safe       134 11
Ball safe       135 1
Ball safe       137 2
```

and at the end it should look like this:

```
Kick-off team   68  0
Attack          77  8
Attack          81  4
Ball possession 86  3
Goal kick       100 10
Ball safe       114 13
Throw-in        123 9
Ball safe       134 11
Ball safe       137 2
```

my solution is

```
awk '{print $NF}' test.txt | sed -re '2,${/(^0$|^1$)/d}'
```

how can i directly change the file, e.g. sed -i?

Comment: this one is solved. thanks for all suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -i '2,$ {/[^0-9][01]$/d}' test.txt
```

- `2,$` lines to act upon, this one says 2nd line to end of file
- `{/[^0-9][01]$/d}` from filtered lines, delete those ending with `0` or `1`

  - `'2,$ {/ [01]$/d}'` can be also used if character before last column is always a space

With `awk` which is better suited for column manipulations:

```
awk 'NR==1 || ($NF!=1 && $NF!=0)' test.txt > tmp && mv tmp test.txt
```

- `NR==1` first line
- `($NF!=1 && $NF!=0)` last column shouldn't be `0` or `1`

  - can also use `$NF>1` if last column only have non-negative numbers
- `> tmp && mv tmp test.txt` save output to temporary file and then move it back as original file
- With `GNU awk`, there is inplace option `awk -i inplace 'NR==1 || ($NF!=1 && $NF!=0)' test.txt`

Comment: this is close to mine. i will use this one. Thanks a lot

Comment: You could replace that `($NF!=1 && $NF!=0)` with `$NF !~ /^[01]$/`.

Comment: @JamesBrown yup, but why use regex if comparison works ;)

Comment: @Sundeep Saving bytes, they don't grow on trees.. ;D

Comment: @JamesBrown, numeric comparisons are faster to process than regexps. Better to save the bytes, or the CPU cycles?

Comment: @ghoti I was just joking, but now that you mentioned it, that program is (probably) run once but it stays here forever. Which one burns more resources? - not to mention these discussions! ;D

Answer (score 1):

Here's my take on this.

```
sed -i.bak -e '1p;/[^0-9][01]$/d' file.txt
```

The sed script prints the first line, then deletes all subsequent lines that match the pattern you described. This assumes that your first line would be a candidate for deletion; if it contains something other than 0 or 1 in the last field, this script will print it twice. And the `-i` option is what tells sed to edit in-place (with a backup file).

Awk doesn't have an equivalent option for editing files in-place -- if you want that kind of functionality, you need to implement it in a shell wrapper around your awk script, as @sundeep suggested.

Note that I'm not using GNU sed, but this command should work equally well with it.

Comment: Awesome, glad I could help! :-) If this answer is the one that works best for you, please feel free to click the checkmark on the left side of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk 'NR==1 || $NF && $NF!=1' file
```

or more cryptic

```
$ awk 'NR==1 || $NF*($NF-1)' file
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -i '1b;/\s[01]$/d' file
```

Other than the first line, delete any line ending in `0` or `1`.